# Get other field if this is included in the array object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Title may sound off but below explains more.

I need to know if an item is included in an array object:

```
[
  { id: 12345, name: "Bob", email: "bob@builder.com" },
  ...
  { id: 13456, name: "job", email: "joe@farm.com" }
]
```

In english: If this `email` present, give me their `id`

```
users = User.all
users.any?{|u| u.email == "bob@builder.com"} # true
```

That will be true. Now, how to get the `id` of the user which is "12345"? Note, I will not know the `id`.

Comment: you should use `detect` like this `user = users.detect {|u| u.email == 'bob@builder.com'}`, you'll get `nil` if no user with that email was found. And if a user is found then you can just use `user.id` to get its id.

Comment: @fanta I need `true` or `false`. If `true`, then get me their `id`. `false` will run other code.

Comment: you can check `if user`, if `user` is `nil`, then you'll execute your `else` in the block.

Comment: @fanta My bad! It's late here in the UK. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using ActiveRecord, it would be faster to query the database for the email:

```
# returns the user id or nil, if not found
User.find_by(email: 'bob@builder.com').pluck(:id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this if you have array of hashes:

```
arr.map do |h|
  h[:id] if h[:email] == "bob@builder.com"
end.compact
```

It will return the value of id in an array of all the hashes which satisfies the condition.